# What is an example in electromagnetism of an irrotational vector field that isn't a gradient?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, vector-fields

Is there any physical situation where this is useful , perhaps in some solenoid configurations or transformers ?

Comment: What do you mean by the gradient of a vector field? Is it the same concept described on this Wikipedia page ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics) ) or something else?

Comment: I can't make complete sense of the question as posed, but perhaps you should consider the betatron. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betatron

Comment: I corrected it , now it's clearere I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the magnetic field of a line carrying a current $I$. In cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$:
$$
B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\hat \phi
$$
with $B$ satisfying the equations of magnetostatics outside the line $r=0$:
$$
\nabla \cdot B = 0 \\
\nabla \times B = 0
$$
You could say that it is the gradient of the potential $f$ with:
$$
B = \nabla f \\
f = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\phi
$$
This makes sense locally, but $f$ is not defined globally on the whole domain of space minus the line $r=0$.

In general, an irrotational field is always the gradient of a potential in a simply connected domain, so such a potential always exists locally. (Note that in the previous example, space minus a line is not simply connected but rather there is a homotopy equivalence with the circle)

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

You can check that it is irrotational using the formula for $B$ and the one for the rotational in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\nabla \times B = \frac{1}{r}(rB_\phi)’\hat z
$$
But actually, you already know this from magnetostatics as I had written before. There are no currents outside the line so directly from Ampère’s law, the magnetic field is irrotational there.

The fact that the curl is rigorously $0$ outside the line but you still have a non zero circulation around it is not contradictory. You cannot apply Kelvin-Stokes’ theorem since a surface whose boundary is the loop would necessarily cross the line current where the field is not defined.

Once again, there are two conflicting definitions for conservative fields: being irrotational or deriving from a potential. They are equivalent when the domain is simply connected and in general will depend on its cohomology. Try looking Poincaré’s theorem and cohomology for more details (closed forms vs exact forms in general).

Comment: So I think that the B field of a charge line current is IxR=B, so the curl of that is zero right? But then if I integrate along a loop around the wire I don't get zero so the field is non conservative .

Comment: I mean the direction of the field B so this is your angle coordinate, but I still don't know if the curl is zero did you use the formula for the cilindrucal coordinates, I'm trying to compute the curl of rxi without coordinates , but a great answer thank you